# Devise: Unable to limit model validation to specific def's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I'm working on the registration aspect of the site currently. I have a main sign up which is just full name, email and password. (aka new.html.erb)

After you fill in that information I direct you to a new site (setup.html.erb) and ask for more info like city, country etc.

On that you also have the edit profile account.

I am trying to make my app more secure and adding restrictions and presence etc in the model. However how can I limit them.

Currently if I do 
validates :email, presence: true,
and I go to a form that doesn't even contain the email for nor permits it I get an error up that I need to add an email.

Also how do I fix this: I make presence true, I input require in html5. But still if I go to my source code and just remove the form and push submit it saves and I can bypass adding info.

Answer (score 0):

`Currently if I do validates :email, presence: true,
and I go to a form that doesn't even contain the email for nor permits it I get an error up that I need to add an email.`

**Fix:**

what you need is a [`conditional validation`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation). If we look at rail guides it says

`Sometimes it will make sense to validate an object only when a given predicate is satisfied. You can do that by using the :if and :unless options, which can take a symbol, a string, a Proc or an Array.`

So in your model you could do something like:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true, if: :need_to_validate?

  def need_to_validate?
    #your condition to check whether you want email validation or not
  end
end
```

**Update:**

You can use **params[:action] and params[:controller]** smartly to *check in which action and controller(hence which view) you currently are in* so your method would be:

```
def need_to_validate?
  params[:action] == your_view_action && params[:controller] == your_controller_name     #your condition to check whether you want email validation or not
end
```

Comment: fantastic looks to be what I need. However. I'm a bit noob here. What would my condition be for the following example:

on the setup.html.erb I have :country, :city etc how do I make it so that it check, if the :example is present on the page, then presence: true